# C# data reader value repeats multiple times while debugging

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am reading data from the `SQL server` table and inserting the same value in the PostgreSQL\SQL database table. It's a data migration process.

The issue is that the data in the SQL is plain text but I see it in the debugging it shows the same value multiple times in watch (visual studio 2015).

Value displays in SQL server as below:

[image: Value displays in SQL server]

Data shows in the visual studio debugger:

[image: Value displays in the debugger]

All migration process works fine but the only table having these type of value does not insert in the `PostgreSQL\SQL` and will throw an exception.

Exception:

```
{"22021: invalid byte sequence for encoding \"UTF8\": 0x00"}
```

Stacktrace:

[image: Exception]

I don't understand the exact problem here. Can anyone please help me understand the cause and solution to the above issue?

Comment: Hi anyone has a solution for the above issue. I am still facing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what whatever's *displaying* the value in SQL Server is just stopping at Unicode code point 0 (U+0000), which is what Windows controls do by default. It looks like Postgres simply doesn't accept that.

I believe you should:

- Try to work out why you've got the value like that in SQL Server to start with. (It could well be a bug in whatever code is doing the insert.)
- Determine what you *want* the data to be. If you actually need the data after U+0000, you'll need to work out whether that means more rows, a different separator etc.
- *Either* fix the data in SQL Server (e.g. by truncating before the U+0000 in every field) *or* perform the truncation as part of the migration (depending on how you're doing the migration).

Comment: NUL is a valid value in UTF8 [but Wikipedia says there's a Modified UTF8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8) that doesn't allow it. And Java uses both of them. SQL Server doesn't care since it uses UTF16, but PostgreSQL obviously does. I wonder what SQL Server 2019 will do with that ...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I haven't seen that "modified UTF-8" used outside Java - I *suspect* Postgres just doesn't support storing U+0000 at all.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/8239.1500489054%40sss.pgh.pa.us would suggest that's the case too.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with PostgreSQL. It is an issue with SQL server itself.
When I select a value in the sql server it gives different outputs in grid and text view.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56234770/sql-server-grid-and-text-output-different-behavior?noredirect=1#comment99088768_56234770

Comment: @Maharshi: That suggests it's *not* an issue with the SQL server *database* itself, but in how you're displaying the data (so potentially in SQL Server Studio). You've got a U+0000 character in your data. I think it's misleading to say your question has "nothing to do with PostgreSQL" when your question uses the postgresql tag and appears to be asking why you can't insert the data into Postgres... how is that *not* about PostgreSQL? For example, I suspect you could see the *exact same issue* without SQL Server being involved anywhere - try inserting `"foo\0bar"` as a value.

Comment: This is what I have realized now. When I actually realized that postgresql is not in the picture, I put a comment so that the question does not mislead anyone.

Comment: @Maharshi: Why not edit the question? That would be a lot more useful than making a statement which *looks* to me like a complaint about the answer and other comments. (Alternatively, leave everything there, but don't claim that the question doesn't have anything to do with Postgres.)

Comment: @JonSkeet . I have updated my question as you suggested. Thank you